# Deployed Django project in heroku environment and the translation is not working

Tags: django, heroku

182/5000
I'm having problems with Django's default translate, in the development environment it works fine, when deploy is done on Heroku does not work. Here are the steps I did:

My Environment URL: **https://portalbigidea.herokuapp.com/**

In my heroku environment this is the django .mo as the command lines below:

You set up the buildpack below in the Heroku environment:
**heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/piotras/heroku-buildpack-gettext.git**

$ heroku run ls locale/en/LC_MESSAGES

Running ls locale/en/LC_MESSAGES on portalbigidea... up, run.3990 (Free)
 **django.mo  django.po** 
Running ls locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES on portalbigidea... up, run.8258 (Free)
 **django.mo  django.po**

### settings/base.py

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["localhost", "127.0.0.1", ".herokuapp.com"]

INSTALLED_APPS = 
    'django_adminlte', 
    'django_adminlte_theme', 
    'django.contrib.admin', 
    'django.contrib.auth', 
    'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
    'django.contrib.sessions', 
    'django.contrib.messages',
    **'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',** 
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 **'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',**  
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware', 
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware', 
]

DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500, ssl_require=True)}

CORS_REPLACE_HTTPS_REFERER     = True
HOST_SCHEME                    = "https://"
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER        = ("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO", 'https')
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT            = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE          = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE             = True
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS            = 1000000
SECURE_FRAME_DENY              = True

**STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")**

**STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")]**

**STATICFILES_STORAGE = whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'**

**from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _**

LOCALE_PATHS = (BASE_DIR + '\locale',)

USE_I18N = True 
USE_L10N = True 
USE_TZ = True 
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-br'

LANGUAGES = ( 
    ('en', _('English')), 
    ('pt-br', _('Brazilian Portuguese')), 
)

I am grateful for all the help that is provided and if I find a solution for this case I inform on the thread below.

**Expected and expected response in the local environment (dev):** 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuXuK.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RxWO.jpg)

**Response received in the Heroku environment in the Herokul cloud (Prod):** 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNPOV.jpg)

Comment: What are you expecting to see happen and what is currently happening? I can't tell what the exact problem is.

Comment: 253/5000
My problem is that in the production environment in the Heroku cloud internationalization does not work. It presents the key texts that are described in the .po file for word translation.
I added a few words to make it easier to understand the problem.

Comment: Did you check to verify the language files on Heroku actually have the translations in them? If that's fine, then open up a shell on heroku and test the translations there. You'll need to figure out at which point is the translation failing. From there you should be able to fix it.